# Leaving site javascript event - onbeforeunload - refresh page/internal hyperlink

Tags: javascript

I'm trying the event onbeforeunload like below, it works fine when I close browser

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    window.onbeforeunload = LeavingSiteHandler;
    function LeavingSiteHandler(e) {
        if (!e) 
            e = window.event;
        //e.cancelBubble is supported by IE - this will kill the bubbling process.
        e.cancelBubble = true;
        e.returnValue = 'You sure you want to leave?'; //This is displayed on the dialog

        //e.stopPropagation works in Firefox.
        if (e.stopPropagation) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
</script>
```

However, when I press F5 to refresh page or click on an internal link, this event will be fired. Is it possible to check whether the clicked hyper link is an internal link? Is it possible to stop this popup message in case I press F5?
Thanks much!

Comment: Unless things have changed, this website says it's basically impossible: http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=202588.

Answer (score 2):

You could write an `onclick` handler for the links in your page, where you remove the `window.onbeforeunload` handler.

But you can’t differentiate between a page refresh and closing a tab/window.

Comment: So, do you have an alternative instead of onbeforeunload?

Comment: Only what I propose in the answer: loop through all the `<a>` elements in your page, add a 'click' event handler, and in that click event handler, remove the `window.onbeforeunload` handler.  But that only enables your links without triggering the confirmation; page refresh will still trigger it.